# how to make a jquery ajax call on an asp.net user control

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have an asp.net user control on which I want to use jquery ajax. It's basically a pop-up form which allows users to enter a name on an auto-complete control.  I don't know how to make this happen using jquery ajax, because in the ajax jquery call i'm supposed to put in a page name in the url: section, and then the method to call.  However, I want to put the method in the .cs file of the user control.  Is there a way to make it happen, or do I have to create a page just to hold the ajax methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user control is different from a page, so you can't call it from your jquery.  If you're using Asp.Net AJAX you can put the method in a page method.  Otherwise you should  put it in a webservice.

Comment: I think he'll definitely want to use a webservice

Answer (score 1):

ICallbackEventHandler is the better option if you do not want to use webservice. It internally makes an ajax call.

Detail about ICallbackEventHandler can be found at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.icallbackeventhandler.aspx

The example of it, in UserControl, can be found at:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27172/The-ICallbackEventHandler

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with "Ajax Request Call" in user control to other resources (web services in this case), If you call a service from your control to outside of you application (another domain) you probably face with "Cross Domain Ajax Request" !!!